# @Html.Action MVC 4 with QueryString Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a question related to the Html.Action in MVC 4 
I want to pass some Querystring Variables with it to the Details view

The code I have now is

```
System.Text.StringBuilder MobileData = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

MobileData.AppendFormat("<a style=\"text-align:left;\" data-role=\"button\"     onclick=\"window.location='" + @Url.Action("Taken_Detail", new { id = tk.ID }) + "';\" data-  ajax=\"true\" data-icon=\"alert\"><span class=\"AgenItems\">{1:dd-MM-yyyy}</span>", tk.ID, tk.Datum);
```

The problem is he would redirect me to localhost/PROJECTNAME/Home/Taken_Detail/2
what I want is Home/Taken_Detail?id=2
what am I missing here I am just starting to learn MVC 4, Every tip is welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your routes contain the `id` parameter. Remove it from the routes and `Url.Action` will change the URL and add your parameter to the query string.

Example:

```c#
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

The `id` parameter will be put after the last slash if you specify it with `Url.Action`.

If you remove it:

```c#
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

The resulting URL will have a query string containing the `id`.

Comment: Ty fero Super nice indeed :P hahah